# How can i upload a pdf page generated with a PHP code?

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload, webserver, cpanel

I have a php page that creates a pdf file and output its on browser. 
I want my php page to upload it on a webserver (cPanel). i've found lots of sites explaining how to upload file througt form and file type but i can't do this. Anyone knows how to?

Comment: Take what you created and save it

Comment: I've tried with FPDF but now i'm using mPDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) to do this easily.

```
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$content = $pdf->Output('doc.pdf','F');
```

This will save the pdf with content `Hello World` as its content in the public_html directory of your webserver.

Or you could use

```
file_put_contents("fileName.pdf", fopen("http://your.url.com/file.pdf", 'r'));
```

Comment: i can't use first method becouse i have to use the "writeHTML" function and if i use FPDF i have this: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method FPDF::writeHTML()". <br> file_put_contents is not working, it have an error on fopen becouse it can't work on remote hosts

Comment: Could you try after declaring the FPDF object as `global`?
From the above example, `global $pdf; $pdf = new FPDF();`

Comment: Funny. It runs flawlessly here.

Comment: if i use global i have to use "file_put_contents" or the first solution?

Comment: Global should be used with the first solution only.

Comment: i've solved the problem using mpdf.
$mpdf->Output("linkToStore", 'F');